# RealTime CRUD Application with nodejs /express and mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, flutter

I wish to create a realtime crud application, using node.js and express as the backend with MongoDB as the database in order to serve flutter frontend
I tried searching on google and GitHub, I found socket.io,  but just for chat applications. my goal is to make a mobile app with synchronized data (like apps using firebase) using node js and MongoDB as Backend. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Socket.Io is a good option for real-time communication. In fact it is a very popular choice. Socket.IO is not created to build chat application. Most of the time, as an example of real-time app everyone bring the concept of chatting. Main purpose of Socket.IO is to transfer data in real-time. It can be any data.

If you are new to this world then I would suggest you to take a look at [FeathersJS](https://feathersjs.com/). You can switch from REST to Real-time or vice versa anytime you want with a couple of lines of code change. A lot of things are hidden from you to make your development easier. Their documentation is good as well.

And the fun part is, FeathersJS is based on ExpressJS and you can choose database driver as you want ([mongoose](https://mongoosejs.com/) is available as an option).